# 500000 user DB is being rather slow

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization

I have a database with the following structure:

```
username,email,ip,hash,salt
```

Currently we have around 600.000 users in this database.
Users are complaining that querying this database is rather slow.

In our tests, we found that it takes around 1.15 seconds to retrieve a user record.
This test is based on the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'test@mail.com'
```

I'm no expert in database management. I know how to get by when using it like a dictionary, however I have no idea on database optimization.

I was hoping I could get some help. Ideally, we'd be able to query the DB like this in under a second on even 10 million users.

Does anyone have any suggestion on optimizing simple queries like this? I'm open to anything right now, even restructuring the database if there's a more logical way to do it. Because right now, they're just ordered in the order that they registered with.

Comment: Add an index on `email`

Comment: also add an index on `username`

Comment: I'm assuming there's resources around the Internet on what 'indexes' does. I'm assuming it's not just adding a number next to the column. I'll report back momentarily. Thanks guys.

Comment: Indexing indeed will help. Fullscan search, when the DB engine has to go through all the records makes it slow. Having an index is a nice way to search in a sorted structure, what is times faster. It is a standard recommending approach in a situation like yours.

Comment: You should use parametrized query in such cases. There is no need to create execution plan every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has two important facilities for improving performance.  For your type of query, 500,000 rows or 10,000,000 rows is just not a big deal.  Although other technologies such as NOSQL can perform the same actions, applications such as yours typically rely on the ACID properties of databases.  A relational database is probably the right solution.

The first facility -- as mentioned elsewhere -- are indexes.  In your case:

```
create index idx_users_email on users(email);
```

An index will incur a very small amount of overhead for `insert` and `delete` operations.  However, with the index, looking up a row should go down to well under 0.1 seconds -- even with concurrent queries.

Depending on other queries you are running other indexes may be appropriate.

The second important capability is partitioning the tables.  This is not necessary for a `users` table.  However, it can be quite useful for transactions and other types of data.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `email` (`email`) Is giving me an error. How many bytes do I index..?

Comment: @user292010 What error? Please show. I just tried Gordon's and your way with a 10million row sample table. Both work and both reduce the SELECT time (in my case) from ~3.5 secs to 0.00 secs, i.e. MySQL cannot even measure :-)

Comment: @PerlDog, if `email` is a TEXT column (and it shouldn't), you need to specify a key length for an index. BTW: `email` should probably be UNIQUE.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ah, ok, I didn't know but assumed [var]char. I'm not very familiar with TEXT and BLOBs (just used them once for trying out but had no real use case).

Comment: If You make the email UNIQUE, you do not neet to explicitly create (another) index on email. The unique constraint builds index on its own.

Comment: Please provide the error message _and_ `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

you could add an index as already mentioned in the comments, but one thought present itself - you are currently retrieving ALL info for that row - it would be more efficient to target the query to only retrieve that information which is necessary - such as

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = 'test@mail.com';
```

also - you should investigate PDO and bound parameters for security.